# Badge for swift answerers?

Tags: feature-request, badges

There was a discussion recently about users who answer questions very soon after they've been posted, and a couple of us thought it'd be a good idea to have a badge for this. It's quite impressive to be able to do this - especially on Puzzling, where it's usually not just about "knowing the answer to a question someone has trouble with" and more about "being able to solve a puzzle someone's composed to challenge the community". Would it be possible to implement such a badge? I would suggest something like:

- Bronze badge **Sharpshooter**: answer 5 questions each within 5 minutes of posting, with answers accepted
- Silver badge **Billy the Kid**: answer 50 questions each within 5 minutes of posting, with answers accepted
- Gold badge **Fastest Gun in the West**: answer 150 questions each within 5 minutes of posting, with answers accepted

OK, maybe the titles could do with improvement...

Comment: It's not like [the problem needs exacerbation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/180276).

Comment: Generally, I'm against this idea (hence DV it), but on a lighter note: Such a badge would need to be accompanied with the according "negative badges of shame" for being fasted with non-accepted answer ;c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A badge for swift answers already exists.

It doesn't require you to lurk watching the new questions for 50+ questions to score a silver badge, as a single answer accepted and with a good score will do it even on a question that is months old, so long as you are first to answer.

Enlightened  : First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more

If you enjoy watching the new questions like a hawk you can even score it multiple times.

### How would you prevent people from posting non-answers?

Surely this will lead to people posting an answers like "Answer to follow" simply to earn the badges. Requiring answers to be accepted to score these badges won't prevent people trying this tactic.

Comment: [Good point!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened?userid=5373) ;-)